# creating time series indices using index template by alias name

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create time series indices but hide that implementation to the user for various reasons and always give the alias name to the user

I have an index - indexA, which is actually an alias to the time series indices -> index_202105, index_202106, index_202107 etc
But, i want to have this mechanism to be managed by index template i.e, user always push their data streams to indexA, which is actually an alias to the time series indices and the time series indices need to be created automatically if doesn't exists.
Is this scenario could be covered with index templates? Could some one please assist here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the main purpose of the new [Data streams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html) feature that was released in 7.9 and index templates are at the heart of this feature, indeed.

Your users can simply write to the data stream and ES takes care of handling the time-based backing indices.

[image]